# How to skip a filter in the filter chain in java

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have 2 filters in my application. Based on some condition, I want to choose whether to execute the second filter or not. Is there a way to do this?

I did some googling with no success. I want the request to continue without executing the second filter. Is that possible?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set an Attribute in your request and check it in your second filter.

```
public class FirstFilter implements Filter {
    //...

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        servletRequest.setAttribute("executeSecondFilter", true);
        //...
        if(someReason)
            servletRequest.setAttribute("executeSecondFilter", false);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}

public class SecondFilter implements Filter {
    //..

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (servletRequest.getAttribute("executeSecondFilter") == null || !((Boolean) servletRequest.getAttribute("executeSecondFilter"))) {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

---

You can simplify the code above like this :

```
public class FirstFilter implements Filter {
    //...

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //...
        if(someReason)
            servletRequest.setAttribute("executeSecondFilter", false);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}

public class SecondFilter implements Filter {
    //..

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (servletRequest.getAttribute("executeSecondFilter") != null) {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

This way you just check the presence of the attribute "executeSecondFilter"

Comment: Nice idea, but this example will throw NPE if the attribute is not set.

Comment: @BalusC, That's why I put a `!= true`, but auto-unboxing won over Object comparison, now it's corrected :)

Comment: You could also use `Boolean.TRUE`. However, I personally find it plain ugly ;)

Comment: I already felt really bad about writing `true` in a condition, and in a way `Boolean.TRUE` would make me feel worse. :P

Comment: @ColinHebert .   HI! do you have any solution for his issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774909/how-to-bypass-or-skip-customfilter-in-mockito-with-springboot-applicaiton

Answer (score 70):

In addition to Colin's answer, there's another way: just don't call [`FilterChain#doFilter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html#doFilter%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse,%20javax.servlet.FilterChain%29), but [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29).

```
if (condition) {
    request.getRequestDispatcher(((HttpServletRequest) request).getServletPath()).forward(request, response);
} else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

But this will skip **all** filters from current on, expect of the ones which are listening on `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>`.

Comment: Good solution. But, we thought we would do the attribute way, cos its little bit simpler.

Comment: You're welcome. This one would however be the only solution when the source code of the other filter is completely out of your control (3rd party and so on).

Comment: The above example forgets the part of the URL after the base servlet path. This will fix that: request.getRequestDispatcher(((HttpServletRequest) request).getServletPath()  + StringUtils.defaultString(((HttpServletRequest)request).getPathInfo()) ).forward(request, response);

Comment: Cojones brings up a good point. Depending on your application you may need more parts of the request than just the servlet path. This StackOverflow answer has a good table showing which parts of the request are which: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21046620/224354

Comment: @DolphinJava: When using `web.xml`, add `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>`. When using `@WebFilter`, add `dispatcherTypes=FORWARD`.

Comment: @Cojones I believe the "?" is missing between `getServletPath()` and `getPathInfo()`. Am I right?

Comment: @Melwin: path info is not query string.

Comment: Thank you @BalusC. Path info can be null so I completed the above comment with:
`String path = httpRequest.getPathInfo() != null ? httpRequest.getServletPath() + httpRequest.getPathInfo() : httpRequest.getServletPath(); request.getRequestDispatcher(path).forward(request, response);`