# Multiple servlet filter control (one filter is a binary)

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, embedded-jetty, apache-karaf

I have two filters in my jetty XML.

One filter was written by us, while the second filter is part of a binary. I want to skip execution of second filter based on the results of the first filter (the first filter does authorization on incoming HTTP request, only if authorization is successful second filter should execute).

I found the following:
[How to skip a filter in the filter chain in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738162/how-to-skip-a-filter-in-the-filter-chain-in-java)

However the catch here is the second filter is part of a binary and I cannot modify it.

Without having source code access to the second filter how can I get this done?

Thanks!

Comment: That is answered in currently highest voted answer of the question you found (i.e. not the currently accepted one). How exactly was that answer unhelpful?

Comment: Reference to the answer that @BalusC is referring to http://stackoverflow.com/a/3738257/775715